# Suppose $X \times Y$ has the product topology. Show that the sequence $(x_n \times y_n)_{n \in N^+}$ ...

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X \times Y$ has the product topology. Show that the sequence $(x_n \times y_n)_{n \in N^+}$ has limit $(x \times y)\in X \times Y$ iff the sequence $(x_n)_{N^+}$ has limit $x$ and $(y_n)_{n\in N^+}$ has limit $y$.

So the sequence looks like $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\cdots,(x_n, y_n)$ right? They want me to show that the sequence has the limit point $(x,y) \in X \times Y$ iff $(x_n)_{N^+}$ has limit $x$ and $(y_n)_{n\in N^+}$ has limit $y$.

So, I have to show that limit point $(x,y) \in X \times Y$ implies that $(x_n)_{N^+}$ has limit $x$ and $(y_n)_{n\in N^+}$ has limit $y$.

Then I have to show that $(x_n)_{N^+}$ has limit $x$ and $(y_n)_{n\in N^+}$ has limit $y$ implies the limit point of the main sequence is $(x,y) \in X \times Y$.

Though, i'm not really show how to go about doing that. I know that A point $x$ in $X$ is a limit point of $S$ if every neighbourhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $S$ different from $x$ itself.

Answer (score 2):

For one implication, use the fact that the projection maps $X\times Y\to X$ and $X\times Y\to Y$ are continuous. For the second, notice that every product neighborhood $U\times V$ of $x\times y$ contains all but finitely many terms of the sequence, and these neighborhoods form a basis for the topology of $X\times Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Take a basic open set $U\times V\ni(x,y)$.

As $x\in U$, $\exists n_x\in\Bbb N$ s.t. $n\ge n_x\implies x_n\in U$.

As $y\in V$, $\exists n_y\in\Bbb N$ s.t. $n\ge n_y\implies x_n\in V$.

Take $n_0=\max(n_x,n_y)$. We can say when $n\ge n_0$?

In the other direction, use the projections on the factors.